# Exception when using string from Web.config in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Straight to the issue, i got this code runs well:

```
var _taxJarClients = new TaxjarApi("sometoken");
var result = _taxJarClients.Categories();
```

but it throws this exception:

> Specified value has invalid Control characters.\r\nParameter name: value

When i change "sometoken" with value from web.config

```
var _taxJarClients = new TaxjarApi(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TaxJarToken"]);
var result = _taxJarClients.Categories();
```

I scratching my head the whole day fixing this issue. thanks!

Comment: put the value in the web.config to a debug variable and see what it actually is

Comment: Not 100% sure but I think appsettings are case sensitive.

Comment: this is working: var token = "value_from_config"; var _taxJarClients = new TaxjarApi(token);

Comment: @Steve i'm pretty sure its already case sensitive

Comment: You will need to encode the token if it has any special characters. For e.g., if your token contains & (ampersend) then you need to use it as &amp; .  If you post your web.config sample token here, then we can help better.

Comment: @sam i'm afraid i cant post it here but it's only alphanumeric without any characters. is there any chance that it is related to encoding?

Comment: @zulkifli if its just alphanumeric, then there is no need for encoding it. In order to isolate whether its web.config issue or TaxJarApi issue, did you get a chance to debug by extracting ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TaxJarToken"] into a variable and notice what has been loaded into variable? If you see correct string in extracted variable then its issue with your TaxJarApi.

Comment: I see your comment on extracting to variable is working fine. Then Its issue with your TaxJarApi. Please post your TaxJarApi constructor as well as Categories to help further. By the way, which line is throwing error ?

Comment: This is the constructor: new TaxjarApi(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TaxJarToken"]); and this line throw the error: _taxJarClients.Categories(); anyway, thanks for your answer, really appreciate. according to this documentation: https://github.com/taxjar/taxjar.net the constructor should be fine.

Comment: @zulkifli try making different call to taxjar api (like a GET request to SummaryRates) to make sure your API key is valid and working fine. If none of them are working then your API key is invalid or reach out to taxjar api.

Comment: @sam thanks for your help dude, really appreciate!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the response guys! really appreciate!

There are some characters appears when i copy-paste it to notepad++ with ANSI encoding and it is works when i remove them.

[image]